# Limits of implicit functions

Tags: limits, implicit-differentiation

I saw a limit today that it was weird because I never saw a implicit function limit.

Can anybody help me with this?

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (2,2)} \frac{x^3-y^3+2-2}{(x-y)^2-2}$$

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (e,1)} \ln(x^2y^2)$$

Comment: you have a higher chance of people helping you when you write your out, not in a image

Comment: where is the implicit function?

Comment: There is no implicit function: you have limits of two variable functions. Since they're continuous at the point where the limit is taken, just substitute.

Comment: @egreg i thought the question is wrong. if it's right then can you tell me the final answer?

Comment: @SteinMeererboer i don't know how to do it.

Comment: @Fleonard The first is $0$, the second is $2$.

Comment: $$x^3-y^3+2-2=x^3-y^3$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the first limit we have $$\frac{8-8}{(2-2)^2-2}=\frac{0}{-2}=0$$